# Why are passenger and cargo airplane noses manufactured separately from fuselages and then put together?

Tags: fuselage, aircraft-manufacturer, nose

I was wondering why the fuselage of a passenger airplane is not built along with the nose? It might be difficult to build fuselage and wings together as one unit, but nose is a small part. Then why is it made separately?

Comment: Do you mean just the radome (it is quite obvious there; it is completely different material), or the whole forward section (this depends on the manufacturer how many parts of the fuselage are built separately before final assembly)?

Comment: Yes, the radome.

Comment: Well, then it should be kinda obvious. The radar must be mounted under it before it is attached to the fuselage and that is done fairly late in the manufacturing process.

Comment: See if you can find a picture that show what you're asking about. If you're not sure how to embed the picture, just edit your post and paste the link in, someone will come along and embed it for you. Realistically, though, the entire aircraft is made up of a whole lot of sub-assemblies that are then put together to make the final whole, the same way cars, ships, and many buildings are. The "nose" is just another sub-assembly that's tacked on in the final assembly process. You can see some of the Airbus process [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus#International_manufacturing_presence).

Comment: Here is one [really good reason why they are separate components](http://abcnews.go.com/US/american-airlines-aircraft-returns-seattle-airport-damaging-bird/story?id=38721606&cid=abcn_tco) it happens quite often actually.

Comment: Maybe you think the fuselage is built in a single piece, but this is not the case. Different sections may be manufactured [at different locations](http://www.airbus.com/company/aircraft-manufacture/how-is-an-aircraft-built/production/). Moreover there are [bulkheads](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17548/what-areas-of-a-commercial-airliner-are-pressurized-besides-the-cabin) at the ends of the fuselage, to deal with pressure differential. The radome is unpressurized and outside this volume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A radome, or nose cone, is essentially a structural cover serving a different purpose than the fuselage. These are made separate because they a special material invisible to the radar mounted beneath them. They are different shapes or sizes depending on the customer specific component they cover (radar antennas) and can be easily removed or replaced.

The radome serves two essential purposes. 1) It covers electronic equipment mounted to the forward bulkhead of the fuselage to protect it from weather, or from view. 2) It acts as an aerodynamic cover for the leading edge of the aircraft.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nose_cone