# Do commercial pilots have their own lavatory?

Tags: pilots

I was wondering if commercial pilots had their own lavatory to the two instead of using a passenger lavatory.

Comment: Also, what about when commercial aircraft are converted for cargo, where the cargo area is unpressurized. Then is the pressure bulkhead just moved aft a bit?

Comment: @Pheric Unpressuirzed cargo holds don't exist on transport jets. See ["Are cargo holds pressurised these days?"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8252/are-cargo-holds-pressurised-these-days)

Comment: @user71659 What about the Beluga?

Comment: @Pheric Not a transport jet by common definition or legally. It can't have passengers either, and bottom section of the aircraft isn't converted, it's unique to the model.

Comment: @user71659 good point lol. Didn't reread my question

Answer (score 0):

In an Airbus A320; pilots share the toilet with the passengers. On AirAsia, a flight attendant blocks access to a toilet when the pilot enters the lavatory.